# Slow traffic(high ping) of MikroTik on Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, ping, mikrotik

I am new to networking.
I installed MikroTik with one Windows server and two Windows 10 clients within Hyper-V. It is routing and I can access the internet from one of the Windows VMs but it is super slow.
I did a basic set-up to make it functional as shown in the screenshot where should I check it to make the traffic faster?

The attached screenshot shows the detailed information.

Thank you for any input.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcd6h.png)

Comment: Do you see that "42% packet loss" at the bottom of the screen shot? That suggests bad cabling or similar. You should have 0% packet loss over such a short link.

Comment: @WarrenYoung thank you for the comment. The thing is it is within Hyper-V. It should be super fast and no loss, right?

Comment: Is this native x86 RouterOS or CHR?